# Google Maps: Map Styles Examples/Library

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know public map styles libraries for Google Maps? I found a few examples here: http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html

But perhaps anyone knows more websites with styled maps examples?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41918/examples-of-google-styled-maps-including-json

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that these links will help you:

#### [How to make Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

> Styled maps allow you to customize the presentation of the standard
>   Google base maps, changing the visual display of such elements as
>   roads, parks, and built-up areas.

You have there few examples:

```
var styleArray = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#00ffee" },
      { saturation: 50 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi.business",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
];
```

### [A great editor](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com)

You have there a lot of instructions about how to use it.

[image]

Comment: I know how to style :) But i'm looking for some inspiration and some existing map styles

Comment: Fore example... :) (i know about the style wizard already)

Comment: And now, all links are gone...

Comment: @Gourav Just fixed and simplified the answer.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Yup, thanks a lot. I have already figured that out. But thanks anyways

Comment: @Gourav I thank you for you the heads-up!

Answer (score 14):

When I found out you could style Google Maps this way I also searched for some kind of repository that lists awesome color schemes. I couldn't find any so I went ahead and created one. Check it out at:

http://snazzymaps.com

You can browse though the styles, copy the JSON style array, or download a full example. It's pretty new but we already have a decent amount of styles and are starting to get some great user submissions.

Comment: Hi Adam, is there a way I can import Google maps into snazzymaps?