# Apply custom styles to maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

First, I want to say I'm not a programmer.
What the issue is, I've looked all around the web to find out how to customize your Google Map.
So I find out you are able to do this using API v3. To find the right code I used the Styled Maps from Google and got the code

```
[
  {
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I have no idea how to use it. I have an `.html` file with this code (no HEAD, BODY, no nothing) :

```
<iframe width="640" height="640" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=53.070843,8.800274&amp;spn=0.002256,0.00456&amp;z=17&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=53.070843,8.800274&amp;spn=0.002256,0.00456&amp;z=17&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Größere Kartenansicht</a></small>
```

How do I combine the code so I get the map with the style I want? 
What do I have to write additionally in notepad so the map style applies?

Answer (score 2):

First off I'll give you a link to the javascript google maps API documentation. Google does a really good job of making their documentation pretty easy to understand, even for non-programmers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

For styling usage take a look at this previous response:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686763/1911676

And here is an example webpage using google's javascript API with the style you posted. It is copied directly from the google maps sample template located here

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/devfest-2010/manila/talk/maps/template.html?r=193&spec=svn197

with some minor changes for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
   <style type="text/css">

/*you can change the map size here*/
  #map {
    height: 640px;
    width: 640px;
  }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {



//change map settings (origin, zoom amount, type...)
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.070843, 8.800274),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP



    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);



//Here is where you put your styles
 var styles = [
  {
   featureType: "all",
   elementType: "labels",
   stylers: [
    { visibility: "off" }
   ]
  }
 ];

/*this sets the style*/
 map.setOptions({styles: styles});

</script>


</head>

<body>
 Other content
<!--this is where your map is. This replaces the iframe-->
 <div id="map"></div>
 Other content
</body>
</html>
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sP7m5/1/

I hope this helps.